# HDF5 C# pinvoke read list of dataset names

Tags: c#, dataset, pinvoke, hdf5, names

Is there an easy way in C# with the pinvoke methods to get a list of dataset names?  The C code uses: "len = H5Gget_objname_by_idx(gid, (hsize_t)i, memb_name, (size_t)MAX_NAME );" in https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/misc-examples/h5_info.c, but that function does not appear in the C# code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Comment: Use a C# HDF5 library

Answer (score -1):

You could use [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) to get the list of dataset names in C# as follows (from HDF5 file `my_file.h5` as an example):

```
 HDFql.Execute("SHOW DATASET my_file.h5 /");
```

In case you want to get the list of dataset names recursively (i.e. the name of datasets stored in groups, subgroups, ...) do the following:

```
 HDFql.Execute("SHOW DATASET my_file.h5 / LIKE **");
```

Check HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) and [examples](http://www.hdfql.com/examples) to get additional information.